# DataFrame object has no attribute 'sample'

Tags: python, pandas, module

Simple code like this won't work anymore on my python shell:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("K:/01. Personal/04. Models/10. Location/output.csv",index_col=None)
df.sample(3000)
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

DataFrames definitely have a sample function, and this used to work.
I recently had some trouble installing and then uninstalling another distribution of python. I don't know if this could be related.

I've previously had a similar problem when trying to execute a script which had the same name as a module I was importing, this is not the case here, and pandas.read_csv is actually working.

What could cause this?

Comment: what is the pandas version? Check using `pd.__version__` .

Comment: The version is 0.14.1

Comment: You're right, sample was added in 0.16.1. I must have inadvertently downgraded my pandas since this worked before. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As given in the [documentation of `DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) -

> **`DataFrame.sample(n=None, frac=None, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=None, axis=None)`**
>
> Returns a random sample of items from an axis of object.
>
> **New in version 0.16.1.**

(Emphasis mine).

`DataFrame.sample` is added in `0.16.1` , you can either -

1. Upgrade your `pandas` version to latest, you can use `pip` for that, Example -

   ```
   pip install pandas --upgrade
   ```
2. Or if you don't want to upgrade, and want to sample few rows from the dataframe, you can also use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample), Example -

   ```
   import random
   num = 100 #number of samples
   sampleddata = df.loc[random.sample(list(df.index),num)]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Instead of 100 samples, it returns 132 as sampleddata.  Always returns more number of samples than specified? what could be the problem?